# Parsing JSON - Javascript - Undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "0": "324",
    "1": "Cavill ",
    "2": "11",
    "3": "100018463",
    "4": "RAR",
    "5": "DummyX",
    "6": "DummyY",
    "7": "Moretext",
    "8": "moretext",
    "id": "lol",
    "teacher": "Specsavers ",
    "rate": "11",
    "teacherid": "100018463",
    "address": "114 Road X",
    "postcode": "WXER 21",
    "lat": "51.511871",
    "lon": "-0.112934",
    "distance": "0.023308985382378217"
  }
]
```

This is held in a variable called "hold".

I am trying to output "teacher" in a div called output1.

Here is my code:

```
obj = JSON.parse(hold);
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = obj[1].teacher;
```

I keep getting undefined.

I tried changing 1 to 0. Same issue - undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

How do I access attribute data from each node/branch?

Comment: Your JSON is inside an Array, so use `obj = JSON.parse(hold[0]);`

Comment: do you have really a JSON **string**?

Comment: @Pugazh What?! No. `hold` would (should) be a string.

Comment: Are you sure you need to parse it? try doing hold[0].teacher

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet ?

Comment: Pranavs `document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = obj[0].teacher;` works, so if it doesn't for you, your JSON string 'hold' probably contains mistakes or isn't a string at all.

Comment: @CodyRaspien Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index starts from `0` and in your data index `1` is `undefined`.

```
obj = JSON.parse(hold);
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = obj[0].teacher;
//------------------------------------------------^^^------
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `hold` is actually a JSON string. And the way you are accessing the parsed json is wrong, it should be `0` since there's only one json string.

```js
var hold = '[ { "0": "324","1": "Cavill ","2": "11", "3": "100018463", "4": "RAR", "5": "DummyX","6": "DummyY","7": "Moretext",  "8": "moretext","id": "lol","teacher": "Specsavers ", "rate": "11","teacherid": "100018463", "address": "114 Road X", "postcode": "WXER 21","lat": "51.511871","lon": "-0.112934", "distance": "0.023308985382378217" }]';
var obj = JSON.parse(hold);
document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = obj[0].teacher;
```

```html
<div id="output1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from **0**. So in your parsed json, `obj[0]` represents the first element. As there is no second element `obj[1]` will be `undefined`.

Use `obj[0]` instead `obj[1]`.

**Working Code:**

```js
var hold = '[{  "0": "324",  "1": "Cavill ",  "2": "11",  "3": "100018463",  "4": "RAR",  "5": "DummyX",  "6": "DummyY",  "7": "Moretext",  "8": "moretext",  "id": "lol",  "teacher": "Specsavers ",  "rate": "11",  "teacherid": "100018463",  "address": "114 Road X",  "postcode": "WXER 21",  "lat": "51.511871",  "lon": "-0.112934",  "distance": "0.023308985382378217"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(hold);
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = obj[0].teacher;
```

```html
<div id="output1"></div>
```