# Access to the values a field in json class

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json class according to the :

```
    [
    {
"AnswerDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
"TOTE": 1,
"Title2": "شاخص های عمومی ارزیابی عملکرد",
"ExpireDate": "1395/03/17",
"TemplateID": 4259,
"EFQMPivotID": 1,
"Title": "برنامه مهندسی نقش و ساختار دولت",
"Wieght": 240.00000000,
"Value": "239.70464100",
"CountPivot": "true",
"AnswerExpireDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
"GrantStart": "2016-05-10T00:00:00",
"Status":     "True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,1,True,False,2,False,False,False,0,1,1"}
 ]
```

I want access to the values status field that get this and pass to jquery.
Please help me.

Comment: Who's and What's stopping you? simple `data[0].AnswerDate`

Comment: ' "Status":     "True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,1,True,False,2,False,False,False,0,1,1"}
 ]'   for exmaple last value that is '1' .

Comment: @MojtabaNava Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately it's not very clear what are you asking. Could you please edit the question to add the code that you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON - Javascript - Undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015722/parsing-json-javascript-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Assume your json array as data. now you can use "var status=$.parseJSON(data)", it give you a normal array. Now if you want to access status then you can do with status['status']. It will return value of status.
[EDIT]

```
<pre><code>
   var jsonObj=   [
    {
        "AnswerDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
        "TOTE": 1,
        "Title2": "شاخص های عمومی ارزیابی عملکرد",
        "ExpireDate": "1395/03/17",
        "TemplateID": 4259,
        "EFQMPivotID": 1,
        "Title": "برنامه مهندسی نقش و ساختار دولت",
        "Wieght": 240.00000000,
        "Value": "239.70464100",
        "CountPivot": "true",
        "AnswerExpireDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
        "GrantStart": "2016-05-10T00:00:00",
        "Status":"True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,1,True,False,2,False,False,False,0,1,1"
    }
 ];
    var res=$.parseJSON[jsonObj];
    console.log(res['Status']);
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var arr = [
    {
"AnswerDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
"TOTE": 1,
"Title2": "شاخص های عمومی ارزیابی عملکرد",
"ExpireDate": "1395/03/17",
"TemplateID": 4259,
"EFQMPivotID": 1,
"Title": "برنامه مهندسی نقش و ساختار دولت",
"Wieght": 240.00000000,
"Value": "239.70464100",
"CountPivot": "true",
"AnswerExpireDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
"GrantStart": "2016-05-10T00:00:00",
"Status":     "True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,1,True,False,2,False,False,False,0,1,1"}
 ]
var getStatusField = arr[0].Status.split(",");
var getLast = getStatusField [getStatusField.length-1];
console.log(getLast);
```

Comment: `var getStatusField = arr[0].Status.split(',');` would be better

Comment: Please vote to my question, that i can vote for you.

Comment: Sorry that is not a right manner If you feel happy for my answer or got any idea in that accept the answer or wait for others answers may be it helpful for you.

Comment: How execute this code in code behind? ' var getStatusField = arr[0].Status; ' is ERROE

Comment: what variable you assigned for the json ??? that name should be come as instead of arr..

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the `,` seperated values of the Status property.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
    {
      "AnswerDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
      "TOTE": 1,
      "Title2": "شاخص های عمومی ارزیابی عملکرد",
      "ExpireDate": "1395/03/17",
      "TemplateID": 4259,
      "EFQMPivotID": 1,
      "Title": "برنامه مهندسی نقش و ساختار دولت",
      "Wieght": 240.00000000,
      "Value": "239.70464100",
      "CountPivot": "true",
      "AnswerExpireDate": "2016-06-06T00:00:00",
      "GrantStart": "2016-05-10T00:00:00",
  "Status":"True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,1,True,False,2,False,False,False,0,1,1"
  }
]
var status = jsonObj[0].Status;
var statusElements = status.split(',');
var res = statusElements[statusElements.length - 1];
console.log(res);
```